# Binomial Distribution: $\mathsf{Binom}(5, 1/4)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

25%  of the workers will get cold in a factory. What will be the probability that at least 4 workers out of 5 will get cold?

I have tried this, can you please help me out if it is wrong or it can be solved easily by any other method.

$P(\text{worker gets cold}) = 25/100 = 1/4$
and $P(\text{worker doesn't get cold}) = 75/100 = 3/4.$

"At least four" means that it can be four or it can be five.

So,

$P(X=4) = {5 \choose 4} (1/4)^4 (3/4)^1 = 0.0147.$

$P(X=5) =  {5 \choose 5} (1/4)^5 (3/4)^0 = 0.000732.$

Then $P(X=4)+P(X=5) = 0.015432.$

is this answer right?

Thanks and help is appreciated.

Comment: "at least more than 4 out of 5" can be interpreted as "at least 5 out of 5". If you mean (and probably you do) "4 or 5 out of 5" then you better write: "at least 4 out of 5". Your answer looks okay to me.

Comment: @drhab thanks for the help. Appreciate

Comment: $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(5, .25)$ and you seek $P(X\ge 4).$ Computation in R statistical software: `sum(dbinom(4:5, 5, .25))` returns 0.015625, so maybe check your arithmetic.

Comment: Edited your Question to remove confusing language and include better formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Your original statement is confusing.  What is the total number of workers in the factory?  I believe that the larger the total number of workers is then the chances of 80% or more get cold is smaller.

Comment: A _repetitious_ comment, not an answer. How is your second sentence helpful toward a solution? I believe no workers would get cold if it were a hot summer day.

Comment: The distribution is binomial, but the first parameter is the number of items i.e. X~Binom(n,.25), so we are interested in finding $(X\gt 0.8n)$, which depends on n.  I assume .25 for the probability is fixed, so the weather is irrelevant.